# How to get around the error "Type mismatch, expected: _$1, actual: Any" in scala?

Tags: scala, generics, types, type-inference

I have a scenario similar to the following example

```
// Reads from somewhere and returns List of type A
trait Reader[A]  {
  def read(): List[A]

}

// Transforms element of type A, performs some operation
// and converts result to string
trait Translator[A]  {
  def translate(a: A): String
}



object Factory {

  def getReader(readerName:String) = {

    readerName match {
     case "one" =>  new Reader[String] {
        override def read() = List("sasha")
     }
     case "two" => new Reader[Int] {
        override def read() = List(3)
     }
     case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
   }

 }

 def getTranslator(translatorName:String) =  {

   translatorName match {
     case "one" => new Translator[String] {
        override def translate (a: String) = a + " " + "nice!!!"
     }
     case "two" => new Translator[Int] {
        override def translate(a: Int) = (a+2).toString
     }
     case "three" => new Translator[Int] {
        override def translate(a: Int) = (a+3).toString
     }
     case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
   }
 }

}
```

Now when I do `Factory.getReader("one").read().map(a => Factory.getTranslator("one").translate(a))`, I get a compile time error "Type mismatch, expected: _$1, actual: Any".

If I am not wrong, compiler is saying it can't tell if the type `A` of reader is same as type `A` of translator.

I am unable to find online, how I can get around this problem ? Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in defining the classes the way I have ?

**EDIT**

Reason I have separate reader and translator is that, they seem to have different jobs, and I could apply more than one translator to the output of one reader (translator 2 and 3 above can be applied to output of reader 2).

Comment: Both, `getReader` & `getTranslator` return **Reader[Any]** & **Translator[Any]** respectively. Thus, you will have a lots of type inference problems. - I assume you only want pone instance of each for every type. If so, you can use **typeclasses** for this, if you are interested I can post an answer with an sketch of the solution.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes I would be interested in knowing. I have updated my question.

Comment: Uhm, since you want multiple instances per type, then **typeclasses** are not longer applicable. Let me see if I can make something else. Does the restriction of only one instance per type holds to **Reader** or not?

Comment: "Does the restriction of only one instance per type holds to Reader or not? " No.

Comment: After thinking about this. What you want to do is not possible, because all the type information would only be available in runtime... Thus the compiler can not prove that your program is correct. Maybe you can play a bit with **ClassTags / TypeTags** - However, I would ask, what is the purpose of the factory receiving an String? Will the name always be available on compile time, meaning it will be constant? or would you get it from runtime? If the last is true, you really can not do too much, but adding a lot of unsafe casts everywhere, and letting the program crash in runtime if any mismatch

Comment: Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez, I am still interested in typeclass solution, assuming its one instance per type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197176/discussion-between-sashas-and-luis-miguel-mejia-suarez).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trouble with your approach is that you've defined a couple methods in which you want to return a different type depending on your input, but that input doesn't have any type information for the compiler to work with.

I.e. your `getReader` function needs to act as both a `String => Reader[String]` and a `String => Reader[Int]` depending on the *value* (not *type*!) of the input. The compiler tries to figure out the common type between those two cases and comes up with `String => Reader[Any]`, but then when you try to *use* that, the loss of the specific type information becomes a problem.

I think the best solution to this is to introduce a type parameter on the input side of your method, e.g.

```
case class ReaderName[T](name: String)

// these would be defined as constants on an object somewhere
val ReaderOne = ReaderName[String]("one")
val ReaderTwo = ReaderName[Int]("two")

def getReader[T](readerName: ReaderName[T]): Reader[T] = readerName match {
  case ReaderOne => new Reader[String] { ... }
  case ReaderTwo => new Reader[Int] { ... }
  case _ => throw ...
}
```

The point here is that you're attaching type information to a name in the form of the `[T]` argument on `ReaderName`. That type information can be used by the compiler to ensure you get a `Reader` instance for the appropriate `T` type based on the `ReaderName` you pass in.

Note that you **shouldn't** try do this:

```
getReader(ReaderName[Int]("one")) // no!
```

because it will likely match `ReaderOne` despite having the wrong type parameter (thanks to type erasure on the JVM), and you'll run into ClassCastExceptions down the road. You should be defining ReaderName instances as constants, and referencing those constants.

A similar approach would be to define the ReaderNames as a sealed trait/abstract class; doing so would allow you to avoid having to throw IllegalArgumentExceptions, and would help protect against the "no!" example above.

```
sealed abstract class ReaderName[T](val name: String)
object ReaderName {
  case object One extends ReaderName[String]
  case object Two extends ReaderName[Int]
}

def getReader[T](name: ReaderName[T]): Reader[T] = readerName match {
  case ReaderName.One => new Reader[String] { ... }
  case ReaderName.Two => new Reader[Int] { ... }
  // no need for a `case _` becase ReaderName is sealed and we have handled all cases
}
```

Comment: Though the above compiles, in intelliJ it highlights the following type mismatch "Required: Reader[T], found Reader[String] with Object {....}"

Comment: @sashas Yeah, IntelliJ gets confused with generic methods like this, and I don't know how to appease it. Maybe things'll get better with Dotty and the intermediate byecode stuff they've teased.